# TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced

Tags: python-2.7

I have a subset of a dataframe and the data is type float. I want to check if the values are increasing or decreasing and have an if statement to handle the results

```
temp = self.__df[column_name].iloc[i:i + 7]
results = [float(sub1) < float(sub2) for sub1, sub2 in zip(temp, temp[1:])]
if all(results) | (not any(results)):
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

I keep getting this error
**return operator.or_(right, left)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

From just printing the results and their types, they were indeed bool type. I also noticed that when the OR statement returned False, the if statement threw the error. Seems like if True works but if False doesn't!